# How to give context menu item for .zip files only?

Tags: macos, object, cocoa, unzip, findersync

I am Developing the zip extractor app in cocoa for which i'm using findersync to show context menu item. But, the problem is item is showing for every file i want to show only for .zip files so how do i do that .

Any Suggestion.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
NSURL *selectedURL = FIFinderSyncController.defaultController.selectedItemURLs[0];
NSURL *fileURL = selectedURL.filePathURL;
if([fileURL.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"zip"]) {
  NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
  NSMenuItem *item = [menu addItemWithTitle:@"Hello" action:@selector(itemTarget:) keyEquivalent:@""];
  item.target = self;        
  return menu;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding a [service](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000101-SW1) instead. That will allow you to add your item for any file not just those in monitored folders. The plist entries for a service allow you to directly specify what file types are acceptable, i.e. Restrict the service to ZIP files

Comment: can you help me out on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51630953/9551844)